# Using login/pass to connect to Active Directory User

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, iis-7.5, ssas

In order to connect a front-end client to my cube, I use msmdpump.dll which permit to connect anyone to ssas over http.

But I have a security issue because the dll access in IIS is anonymous. So, anyone who find the URL of the dll can connect to my cube, because no login/pass is required. We use this solution because the local username and domains are transmit to IIS when the user connect to the website.

The architecture is this :

- One website on a IIS server (the name of the Domain is AA)
- The cube on SSAS on a second server (the name of the Domain is AA - so the same domain as IIS server)
- Allow users are in Active Directory (in the Domain AA)
- xxx users connect to the website (local user and local domain on each computer)

In order to avoid the Anonymous mode, I would like to do something like this :

- The user go to the website
- The website ask credentials to user
- User put his username and password from the Active Directory in any form of the website and submit informations
- IIS recognize him and identify the user as the user of the domain

This is an example of my description :

- I have an account on AD "AA" Domain
- This account is AA\toto and my password is 1234
- This user is allowed to connect to ssas
- I'm from home (without the domain AA), and I go to the cube website
- A form appears asking me my login and password
- I put AA\toto and 1234
- IIS allow me to go to another page with credentials of my AD account

Anybody knows if it's possible ?

If anybody knows which authentification mode Excel use in ODC file in order to connect the SSAS, maybe it would be a good start point.

EDIT :
I tried to put "Basic authentication" in IIS on DLL Website. If I put an account which not exist on the domain, the access is denied on Excel. But if I put the good account, Excel success to connect to ssas. I think I'm close to the solution. I will try to make a login page and seee if the connexion works.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Provides an Active Directory Membership Provider by default which will allow you to authenticate users using Active Directory.

It requires very little to get started, in the web.config of the website you simply add:

```
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />

    <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and a relevant connection string:

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://My-Connection-String,OU=users,OU=CSL,DC=your-domain,DC=Local" />
```

This should help you get started, in my MVC app, this was all it took to start recognising credentials of users with Active Directory accounts... the standard username and password form in MVC worked immediately.

However... authenticating against roles can get a little more difficult! Depends if you need that functionality though...

Edit: More info on the LDAP connection string here...
https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string

Comment: Not sure that what I search because your solution allow to access to protected pages when the AD account is verified. I want transform the instance of the website from anonymous to AD existing user.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, if you want to restrict access to particular pages you can use the "IsAuthenticated" attributes? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: As you know, when you execute a IIS website as anonymous User, you specify in IIS the credentials to use : specific user or application pool user. I'm looking for a method to use the website with specific credentials, which are in Active Directory. I'm not sure your method will use these credentials on website, but I will test and make a review.